# Printing an equation from a 2D array using a for loop

Tags: php, arrays

```
$string = 3;

for ($i=0; $i<$string; $i++) {

  for($j=0; $j<$string; $j++) { 

    print $arr[$i][$j] = rand(1,5); 

}

  print "<br>";

}
```

Basically this code will output something like

5 5 4

2 5 2

4 5 3

I want to print on the screen something like 5 + 5 + 4 + 2 + 5 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 3 = 35

I have tried multiple methods but am struggling when getting the + to print in the right places.

Comment: Where/when are you summing the value?

Comment: I had created a second loop that would sum the values. My only problem is how to get the plus to come after each value as they are coming from an array. Sometimes I get an issue where it prints 5 5 4 + 2 5 2 + 4 5 3. Instead of printing between each value, it prints the + between each array

Comment: I'm not sure how you are doing that your code doesn't show any `+`s in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly then you can use the following code:

```
$arr = array();
$string = 3;
$temp = array();
$sum = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < $string; $i++) {

    for($j=0; $j<$string; $j++) { 

        $arr[$i][$j] = rand(1,5); 
        $sum += $arr[$i][$j];
        $temp[] = $arr[$i][$j];
    }

}

echo implode(' + ', $temp).' = '.$sum;
```

Result:

```
2 + 5 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 2 + 5 + 3 + 1 = 28
```

**EDIT** (without the `implode` function [OP request in comments]):

```
$arr = array();
$string = 3;
$temp = '';
$sum = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $string; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $string; $j++) {  
        $arr[$i][$j] = rand(1,5);
        $sum += $arr[$i][$j];
        if ($i == ($string - 1) && $j == ($string - 1)) {
            $temp .= $arr[$i][$j];
        } else {
            $temp .= $arr[$i][$j].' + ';
        }
    }
}

echo $temp.' = '.$sum;
```

Result:

```
1 + 2 + 1 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 5 = 26
```

Comment: You could get rid of `$sum` and do `echo implode(' + ', $temp).' = '. array_sum($temp);`..

Comment: is there any way to do this without using the implode function? :)

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis if i had a variable such as $inputnums = "12, 20, 30, 40"; is there any way for me to put these into an array?